# MySQL - SELECT to return ids from same table in a subselect

Tags: mysql

The issue to be addressed is the following:

1. All ids where matrix_id are the same and relationship task with stage_id = 1 is complete = true and current_phase = 5
2. And All ids where deviation_id are the same and the task with stage_id = 1 and complete = true and current_phase = 5
3. All ids where stage = 2 and current_phase is [2,3 or 4] and complete = false (Sorted)
4. Once they return the data correct, i need to make them a single query, so it would return all the ids for all three queries

**Sample data and queries https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iWC2SrAmV8nKZNR9dqU5Qm/3**

I would say Kirs Kringle had a very good solution there, but still missing few things.

1. First query is returning two items, the second (ID #4) with stage_id = 1 is completed but not is not in the current_phase = 5, so it should not be returned
2. Same happening with the second query, where the second item should not be returned because its relationship task in stage 1 is not in the current_phase = 5
3. Third query is ok already.
4. It needs to be a single query with all 3 queries together.

Comment: @Strawberry tks a lot for the feedback, i think im going to use for the moment the db in fiddler created by Kirs Kringle

Comment: Edit your question accordingly

Comment: @Strawberry tks i think now is much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is very difficult to understand. I did the best I could with the info you provided.

---

I used the following to create the table in the second shown example (by no means should you use this for your real table schema. I put this together quickly):

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS TEST; 
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TEST.test_table (
    ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    SYSTEM_ID INT(10) NOT NULL,
    TYPE_ID INT(10) NOT NULL,
    STAGE_ID INT(10) NOT NULL,
    CURRENT_PHASE INT(10) NOT NULL,
    COMPLETE BOOLEAN,
    MATRIX_ID INT(10),
    DEVIATION_ID INT
);
INSERT INTO TEST.test_table (ID,SYSTEM_ID,TYPE_ID,STAGE_ID,CURRENT_PHASE,COMPLETE,MATRIX_ID,DEVIATION_ID)
VALUES
  (NULL,1,1,1,5,true,1,NULL),
  (NULL,1,1,2,1,false,1,NULL),
  (NULL,1,2,1,4,false,2,NULL),
  (NULL,1,2,2,1,false,2,NULL),
  (NULL,1,2,1,5,true,NULL,1),
  (NULL,1,2,2,1,false,NULL,1);
```

---

I then created the following queries to answer your questions 1,2, and 3. I'm not sure if you wanted them all answered with one query I do not think anything in the set of data you provided would meet that criteria I decided to not entertain it.

---

> ## 1 - All ids where matrix_id are the same and the task with stage_id = 1 is complete = true:

```
SELECT
  MAX(ID) ID
FROM TEST.test_table tt 
WHERE MATRIX_ID IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY tt.MATRIX_ID
HAVING SUM(tt.COMPLETE) = (COUNT(*)-1)
;
```

**Answer is**: ID 2

**Note**: I guess this wouldn't be considered checking if STAGE_ID is 1 and true, but I think it effective gets you the same result and as time goes on it will always make sure that the task before it was completed as the SUM of the completed boolean field should always be 1 less than the total number of tasks BUT stay you start stacking more tasks you will need to refine this a bit and come up with something a bit more exact.

---

> ## 2 - And All ids where deviation_id are the same and the task with stage_id = 1 and complete = true:

```
SELECT
  MAX(ID) ID
FROM TEST.test_table tt 
WHERE tt.DEVIATION_ID IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY tt.DEVIATION_ID
HAVING SUM(tt.COMPLETE) = (COUNT(*)-1)
;
```

**Answer is**: ID 6

---

> ## 3 - All ids where stage = 2 and current_phase is [2,3 or 4] and complete = fal:

```
SELECT
  tt.ID
FROM TEST.test_table tt 
WHERE tt.STAGE_ID = 1
AND tt.CURRENT_PHASE IN (2,3,4)
AND tt.COMPLETE = false
;
```

**Answer is**: ID 3

---

I think that by understanding the GROUP BY command and the HAVING command you will gain some insight into how you might solve these problems.

You can test this out here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dD67jzQpENdJ5YSLBxoLbD/0

Comment: I think that is going to help me a lot already, i know is bit hard to explain. The only thing i would ask is what if i need to add the current_phase = 5, from the task where the stage is 1, because apart from the complete being true, there are cases that the task is complete but not in current_phase 5.

Comment: I have completely changed the way i presented the question, im trying to finish the query but no success yet, you had a very good approach there, now i just need to include in the query the current_phase = 5 for the task in stage one, do you think that is possible?